# How to go through each column and remove duplicates in Excel (VB)

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I'm looking to go through 7776 columns of data and remove duplicates.

I can't get remove duplicates to work with relative cell referencing.

This works ...

ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B31").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

but changing it to relative so I can iterate though the columns doesn't work.

I tried to pass the cells into an array, then find duplicates and then return those values to a new sheet but same column position.

Any help is much appreciated! I've been banging my head on a brick wall most of today!

Lewis

Comment: Please add to the question your code which you changed to relative, with description what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Count you Max rows and columns, then loop through the columns.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, Col As Long, r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    Rws = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=r, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Col = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=r, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    For x = 2 To Col
        Range(Cells(1, x), Cells(Rws, x)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the code below a try. It looks at how many columns there are and iterates through them. For each column, it looks at the number of rows there are and then removes the duplicates from that column. The `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Calculation` bit at the beginning and the and end should help in speeding things up.

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim i As Long
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of the sheet your data is in")
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

With Ws1
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(LastRow, i)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next i
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for a solution which is independent of the Excel version used (RemoveDuplicates needs Excel2013 or newer), I suggest copying the range into an array, collecting unique values into a dictionary, and copying back the unique values alone:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueCol()
    ' remove duplicate values from each column
    ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471130/how-to-go-through-each-column-and-remove-duplicates-in-excel-vb
    ' 2015-12-26
    Dim Rng As Range, dst As Range
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim values As Variant, el As Variant
    Dim col As Long, row As Long, ncols As Long, nrows As Long

    Set Rng = Range("C2:K40")
    nrows = Rng.Rows.Count
    ncols = Rng.Columns.Count

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For col = 1 To ncols
        MyArray = Rng.Columns(col)
        For row = 1 To nrows
            dict(MyArray(row, 1)) = True
        Next row
        values = dict.Keys()
        Rng.Columns(col).Clear
        Set dst = Rng.Columns(col).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(values), 1)
        dst.Value = Application.Transpose(values)
        dict.RemoveAll
    Next col
End Sub
```

Here, the source range is hardcoded as C2:K40. You will need a reference to the MS Scripting object.